# run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@charset'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, stylesheet

I have a CSS Stylesheet which contains following code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

I am facing these ERRORS

/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(1189,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@charset'
(1189,10): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '"utf-8"'
(1189,17): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ';'

Comment: Perhaps the minifier simply can't handle @ commands. How about just saving the CSS file without it, maybe throwing in a UTF-8 BOM (although that shouldn't be necessary). Otherwise, maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970293/mvc4-bundling-css-failed-unexpected-token-found-import) will help, which seems to deal with a similar enough issue.

Comment: Yep. Did you try with a Media Query at-rule? With `@font-face` also?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message, but in my case I was trying to load the CSS file with a `<script>` tag.

Loading it with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css">` worked as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Only one `@charset` may appear in a CSS and it must appear at the very start of the document. It must **NOT** be preceded by any characters, not even comments.

Most of the time, It's due to bundle `CSS` along with another 'CSS' files.
My guess is that, you are using a bunch of `css'es` in a single bundle and **The topmost CSS in bundled files, Only can have `@charset "utf-8"`.**
Therefore you can set `@charset "utf-8"` at the topmost CSS file in `Bundle` statement (and make sure that you haven't use another `@charset` declaration other than `"utf-8"` if so, then you need to split bundled files into separate bundles, so that every `@charset` accommodate at the top of it's bundle order).

NOTE: Since the HTTP header has a higher precedence than the in-document `@charset` declaration, you may also want to omit `@charset` statements and declare it in HTTP header.