# How to add jQueryUI library in MVC 5 project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I've just installed Visual Studio 2013 and started new MVC 5 project. I'm kind of new in MVC developing and I can't figure out how to add libraries in my project.

I see some similar parts. For example, on the `_Layout.cshtml` I have this code:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Then in the `packages.config` file:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Then as far as I know something happens on `Global.asax`

So, I've downloaded jQuery UI libraries with .js and css files. My question is:
Where and what should I add in term of use this libraries everywhere like default libraries (bootstrap or jquery)?
And jQuery UI has 3 folders with content. I added this folders with all content to my project, I just need to add references.

Comment: You should look into Nuget. This is basically the preferred way of adding dependencies to .net projects now.

Comment: Can you be more specific=) Can you provide a couple steps list, please

Comment: Bryuk - Right click your References in your project and select "Manage Nuget Packages". From there you can search for packages, update packages, etc. When you create a new MVC5 application, it automatically installs a bunch of Nuget packages for you: jQuery, Bootstrap, etc. Find out more at www.nuget.org

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The code you see rendering css and scripts on your `_Layout.cshtml` page (i.e. `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")`) is called **bundling**. Check out some info here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

So, to add jQueryUI you would do the following:

In your Global.asax.cs file you should see a number of registrations:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

This goes to the `BundleConfig` class which registers any bundles. For jQueryUI you could do the following:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

This is creating a new script bundle called `~/bundles/jqueryui`.

Then it can be added to your layout page by doing this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Then you'll do the same for css:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

and add it with

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
```

**Note:**

- In MVC4, a non-empty project already has jQuery set up. For an empty project you would have to add it yourself. Not 100% sure about the new MVC 5.
- You can install jQueryUi from NuGet, but the official package doesn't add this bundling stuff.
- You could just do the old fashioned referencing of you css and js files (e.g. `<script language="JavaScript" src="~/Scripts/jQuery.ui.1.8.2.js" />`

Comment: If you want the entire theme then you only need to reference jquery.ui.all.css

Comment: There's an issue with only including jquery.ui.all.css. [See hear to read about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970293/mvc4-bundling-css-failed-unexpected-token-found-import)

Comment: @Luminous `all.css` seems to be working OK in a project I've just created.

Comment: Great instructions @simon-c. The CSS file naming conventions are different in jQuery UI version 1.12.  Devs can remove the "jquery.ui." prefix after "base/" in those paths. This worked for me: bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css"));

Answer (score 33):

The css bundle should look as follows for version 1.11.1 now:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
        "~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/all.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/base.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/button.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/core.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/draggable.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/menu.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/resizable.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/selectable.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/selectmenu.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/slider.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/sortable.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/spinner.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/tabs.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/tooltip.css"));
```

`

Answer (score 23):

To install jQueryUI + the latest version of jQuery you can use NuGet:

```
Install-Package jQuery.UI.Combined
```

This will update your existing jQuery libraries to the [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.Combined/).

You can then reference this by going in `App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` and add:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/base/all.css"));
```

You can then use it on individual pages or globally in `_Layout.cshtml`

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") // Add to <head> tags
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui") // Add above </body>
```

Comment: Oh my god.  I have been stuck for an entire day because I've been adding the script to the head and not the body... Thank you.

Comment: @Rinktacular You're welcome! We've all been there :)

Answer (score 5):

After installing JQuery ui using the NuGet add following snippets to BundleConfig.cs as shown below

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

also

```
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

[image: here is my screen shot]

Now add following snippets to your _Layout.cshtml as shown below

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
```

and

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

[image]

I just want to make it little bit clear, hope this will help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the accepted answer by Simon C, indeed it is necessary to bundle jQuery UI js:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
  "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

and the use by calling:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

at the same time as of 23 Jan 2021 the css files does not include jquery.ui.* prefix.

It is also not necessary to include these individual files as it specified in the header of **jquery-ui.css**:

- Includes: core.css, accordion.css, autocomplete.css, menu.css, button.css, controlgroup.css, checkboxradio.css, datepicker.css, dialog.css, draggable.css, resizable.css, progressbar.css, selectable.css, selectmenu.css, slider.css, sortable.css, spinner.css, tabs.css, tooltip.css, theme.css

So, one can just write this to bundle jquery-ui.css:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    .Include("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css");
```

and use it in pages by means of:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
```