# Installing jQuery-UI is missing all style sheets, what did I do wrong?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

VS2013 update4, package manager, installed jQuery-UI, but no CSS came with it.
What am I missing?
Is there something I have to manually download?
this is non-intuitive for a package, no?

Comment: download the latest version from here http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.11.4.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS will be there, but not where you expect. Assuming you installed the `jQueryUI-combined` package the CSS will be somewhere like:

```
Solution_folder\Project_folder\Content\themes\base
```

Try setting `Show all files and folders` to on in Visual studio, then navigate through that folder structure and include them in your project.

If it's not there, make sure you check `App_Themes` as well.

Comment: The reason I ask is because my autocomplete has a transparent background, looks like c#@p... no idea why

Comment: @Beau The files in that folder should be yeah. Can you see any files in that folder?

Comment: yes I do, thank you. I thought, however, that NuGet packages were usable out of the box... guess this isn't... I added references to them like this:@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") but the autocomplete background is still transparent...

Comment: @Beau No problems, for the bundle setup make sure you follow the steps outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081328/how-to-add-jqueryui-library-in-mvc-5-project